# How to form oracle function - if /else return different TIMESTAMP values

Tags: oracle, sql-function

I am trying to create a sql function that returns one TIMESTAMP value if a certain condition is met, or else return a TIMESTAMP value plus an extra 30 days. Here is my function as created (but not compiling):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "DUEDATE" (DATE_A IN TIMESTAMP, NUM_DAYS IN NUMBER, DATE_B IN TIMESTAMP) 
RETURN TIMESTAMP AS 
BEGIN
  IF SYSDATE - CAST(DATE_B) < 30
    RETURN CAST(DATE_A AS DATE) + (((NUM_DAYS/30) + 1)) * 30
  ELSE
    RETURN CAST(DATE_A AS DATE) + ((((NUM_DAYS/30) + 1)) * 30) + 30
END;
```

Any help greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Do you write all your Java in caps-lock too? There's no requirement for this in PL/SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend getting a good pl/sql book, or read the oracle documentation.  You had a bunch of syntax errors.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "DUEDATE" (DATE_A IN TIMESTAMP, NUM_DAYS IN NUMBER, DATE_B IN TIMESTAMP) 
RETURN TIMESTAMP AS 
BEGIN
  IF SYSDATE - DATE_B < 30 THEN
    RETURN CAST(DATE_A AS DATE) + (((NUM_DAYS/30) + 1)) * 30;
  ELSE 
    RETURN CAST(DATE_A AS DATE) + ((((NUM_DAYS/30) + 1)) * 30) + 30;
  END IF;    
END;
```

Comment: thanks. You are right, I should have dug deeper and gotten a book first. I am a java guy writing occasional sql. Thanks!

Comment: Oracle doco, version 12.1 PL/SQL reference: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/LNPLS/toc.htm 
SQL reference: https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/toc.htm

Comment: I think you still need to `CAST_DATE_B AS DATE)`, otherwise you're comparing an interval with a number, which is doing some kind of implicit conversion which makes it always true - I guess to strings , so it's comparing the +/- of the interval with '3' as string comparison.

Comment: yes that line was missing the cast but i got the gist of it and got the function to work.

Answer (score 2):

Your calculations seem to equate to adding either 30 or 60 days to `DATE_A`, so I'm not sure why you are dividing and multiplying. I'm also not sure why you're working with dates when the arguments and return value are timestamps; you can stick to timestamps and intervals instead:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "DUEDATE" (DATE_A IN TIMESTAMP, NUM_DAYS IN NUMBER, DATE_B IN TIMESTAMP) 
RETURN TIMESTAMP AS 
BEGIN
  IF DATE_B > SYSTIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '30' DAY THEN
    RETURN DATE_A + (NUM_DAYS + 30) * INTERVAL '1' DAY;
  ELSE
    RETURN DATE_A + (NUM_DAYS + 60) * INTERVAL '1' DAY;
  END IF;
END;
/
```

Or

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION "DUEDATE" (DATE_A IN TIMESTAMP, NUM_DAYS IN NUMBER, DATE_B IN TIMESTAMP) 
RETURN TIMESTAMP AS 
BEGIN
  RETURN DATE_A + (NUM_DAYS + CASE WHEN DATE_B > SYSTIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '30' DAY
                                   THEN 30 ELSE 60 END) * INTERVAL '1' DAY;
END;
/
```

As far as I can see that gets the same results - except it will retain fractional seconds, which are lost when you cast to date.

---

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=8a9780ab41f6ab424506358387777d1b) running both functions for every day this year, and also showing the result of @OldProgrammer's version with and without the `CAST(DATE_B AS DATE)` - notice (a) that the first two functions retain fractional seconds, and (b) that the third gets different results until you reach 30 days ago (running today, that changes on 2018-06-26 on page 18 of the results).